# SQL Code question - Why would you need to drop table before create table

Tags: sql

I don't understand why the table is dropped before creating it in the is this query I am reviewing. Can anyone help to explain this better? Thank you!

```
DROP TABLE #Table1
CREATE TABLE #Table1(
  ID INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If table exists already you will get an error. That is why you clean env first:

```
DROP TABLE #Table1; 
CREATE TABLE #Table1( ID INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID) );
```

I would use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` to be safe.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1235d8ad2a066fd648a4ed1b73fde972)**

Comment: @SalmanA That is why I added **IF EXISTS**. Second argument is that some scripts are invoked multiple times from the same session(SSMS) so first run will end up with error, but after you  create table once you could invoke it multiple times without any problems.

Comment: Just for the sake of thoroughness, prior to SQL Server 2016, you'll want `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table1','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Table1;`. But if you have the option, `DROP .... IF EXISTS` is so much less typing, and so much clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it didnt answer my question. I dont understand why the drop table statement is used here. :)

Comment: @ANN It is common pattern in SQL world. Think like this - you are developing some code and you want to run in multiple times without any change. If you create table once, then second execution will end up with error. Using `DROP-CREATE` pattern you are free of this problem.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Thank you! I am new to SQL and still learning. This really helped!

Answer (score 1):

`DROP` before `CREATE` is common in SQL script. It is for making sure to delete the old table before making a new one. 
This is because SQL script will not halt if the table exists. Not just on tables but it is common on creating the database.

For example, if we running a restoring backup script. In the create table process if the table already exists it will raise an error but the script will not stop. It will be a problem if the data is not restored properly.